# PHP get objects based on their array position and a limit

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects (generated by TYPO3) which is coming from the variable `$times` and looks like this:

```
 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (8 items)
   0 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=1, pid=5)
   1 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=4, pid=5)
   2 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=5, pid=5)
   3 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=6, pid=5)
   4 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=7, pid=5)
   5 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=2, pid=5)
   6 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=3, pid=5)
   7 => Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Timeprototypepersistent entity (uid=8, pid=5)
```

What i would like to do is to get for example the first two objects based on their position in the array. The number that defines how many objects are to be retrieved is a variable which is going to be changed if the client wishes to.

Now the difficult part, is that after i retrieve the first two objects, i would like to retrieve the next two when a button in FrontEnd is pressed.

**Basically when a button is pressed, the next two objects should be selected.**

So far i got this:

```
$limit = $settings['list']['paginate']['itemsPerPage']; // How many objects should be retrieved
$setLastItem = 0; // sets the biggest position in the array of the selected objects
$args = $this->request->getArguments(); // Gets the arguments of the button
$getLastItem = $args['arguments']['lastItem']; // reads the last retrieved position of the last selected objects

if (!$getLastItem) {
    $getLastItem = 0;
} // evaluate if it is NULL. (By the first load of the page, there are no arguments available)
```

After that i tried the following:

```
while ($getLastItem < count($times)) {
    $results[] = $times{$getLastItem++};
}
```

Which gives me the objects after the selected last item.

**Goals:**

1. how can i get it to give me only the next two objects ($limit variable)
2. how do i get the biggest array position of the current selected objects in order to pass it on the FrontEnd

**Concept:**

All this code takes place on an action called `listAction`.
On the first load of the page the `listAction` will retrieve the first two objects from the array. These objects, will be displayed on the FrontEnd.

```
$this->view->assignMultiple([
    'times' => $results,
    'lastItem' => $setLastItem
]);
```

The assigned array (times) will render the information of the selected objects and the 'lastItem' will be placed as an argument on the button.

```
<f:form.hidden name="lastItem" value="{lastItem}"/>
```

When the button is pressed, it will send a request to the `listAction` again passing the argument of the last item (`$getLastItem` variable) that was displayed in the FrontEnd.

Now the `listAction` should get the next two objects starting from the position of the `$getLastItem` variable which is the last selected object from the previous selection. The objects that are going to be displayed/selected are definded by the variable `$limit`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `how can i get it to give me only the next two objects ($limit variable)`-> you have to pass last index of array along with `$limit`, now that function will give you next 2 index array from the last sended index. 2 -> I am unable to understand it

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have updated the question with the concept. this might help you understand the question better

Comment: Try `array_slice(yourArray, $getLastItem, $limit);`

Comment: @ElSam I am pretty sure this won’t work because it is an array of objects and not an array. I think I tried it before but I got an error saying that array_slice needs an array and not objects

Comment: an Array of objects is still an array, so it should work, unless your list of objects is not an array to begin with.